# Making request through google drive ServiceAccountCredential is not returning in IIS/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, google-drive-api

we have given all the possible rights to folder and also change the application pool identity / default app pool/ administrator/ application pool 4.0 /default application pool but still my application is not returning from authentication method of usercredential of google drive service.

I have the following users on the website application folder, with full read/write permissions:

```
•NETWORK SERVICE
•IIS_IUSRS
•SYSTEM
•Administrators
•me
```

we are using client id and client secreat key for authentication.

if we are running same code from visual studio then its working fine but if are running same code from iis then we are facing following issue of only google drive service rest functionality of application is working fine.

```
"Making request through google drive ServiceAccountCredential is not returning in IIS 7/ASP.NET"
```

we are using following :

Visual Studio 2010, 
.Net framework 4.0, 
IIS 7.0 ,
Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Following comments will help you to solve the above issue.
1. Add read/write rights to your directory
2. Modify the FileDataStore.cs file of GoogleApisClient's source code and replace the 'Old Line' with 'New Line'

Old Line :

```
folderPath =Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), folder);
```

New Line :

```
folderPath = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("GTemp"), folder);
```